# How to not pass header and footer into each page

Tags: angular

My website will have a sidebar, header, footer, and content. Something like this:
[image]
That's an easy grid I can implement.
But on some pages I want my content to have an additional sidebar on the right. The problem is that I want it to move the header and the footer:
[image]
The only solution that I found is to pass the header and the footer into each page. But this is not DRY.

So, how can I do that? Is this even possible? If so, how? I can't even imagine how the final code should look like...

P.S. I read about auxiliary outlets, but don't know how can I apply them to this issue.

Comment: Did you have a read of this article? https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-router-nested-routes-and-nested-auxiliary-routes-build-a-menu-navigation-system/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here another answer after I understood your problem a bit better :)

Look at this codepen:
https://codepen.io/spierala/pen/wvBWaWV

For the CSS I also used bootstrap flex classes, but the main magic is `position: absolute` on the `div.content-sidebar` so it can "escape" of its parent container). Also the parent container `div.content-container` is not allowed to have positioning itself to make that work.

The app-component must decide over giving footer and header a margin.

The routed component inside the router outlet must decide over the margin of the `div.content`. Because `div.content-sidebar` is absolute positioned it can not influence the width of `div.content` anymore. We have to fix that manually by adding margin if the content-sidebar is visible.

So you can use Angular to add the css classes / styling which are needed for adding or removing the margins in app-component and in the routed components - depending on the content-sidebar visibility.

How will app-component and routed component know?
You could introduce a Angular service which will hold the information if a sidebar is visible or not. The routed component could set that information. app-component reads it.

EDIT: regarding the "escape"... if header and footer have fixed heights then you could use negative margins on the content-sidebar instead of the  position:absolute approach

If footer and header have a height of 50px then the `div.content-sidebar` margins look like this:

```
.content-sidebar {
  margin-top: -50px; // - header height
  margin-bottom: -50px; // - min footer height
}
```

I created another codepen here: https://codepen.io/spierala/pen/PowzmzL
You will also see that `div.content` does not need margin anymore since the content-sidebar is not positioned `absolute`.

Comment: Wow, that's an awesome answer! Could you please explain a bit more about your edit, because my header and footer indeed have fixed heights. I try to remove `position: absolute` and add `margin-left: -200px` to the `content-sidebar`, but it make it have some 'gaps' on the top and on the bottom. (Please, have a look at my forked CodePen https://codepen.io/Feeco/pen/KKwMaRo).

Comment: I added more information about the EDIT to the answer

Answer (score 1):

you'd have your wrapper 1 component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-one',
  template: `
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <div class="main">
      <header></header>
      <div class="content><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  `
})
export class WrapperOneComponent { ... }
```

then wrapper 2:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-two',
  template: `
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <div class="main has-content-sidebar">
      <header></header>
      <div class="content><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <content-sidebar></content-sidebar>
  `
})
export class WrapperTwoComponent { ... }
```

then structure your routes:

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: WrapperOneComponent,
    children: [
      // all not needing sidebar
    ]
  }
  {
    path: '',
    component: WrapperTwoComponent,
    children: [
      // all needing sidebar
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, @bryan60! Thanks for the answer! The problem is that I have to declare content-sidebar inside router-outlet since it will be unique for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a data property to your routes (see more info here: https://angular.io/guide/router):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'comp1',
    component: Comp1Component,
    data: { showContentSideBar: true }
  },
  { path: 'comp2',
    redirectTo: '/Comp1Component',
    data: { showContentSideBar: false }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/comp1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

In your app-root component you can read that data with the `showContentSideBar` flag like this:

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      }),
      filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
      mergeMap((route) => route.data))
      .subscribe((event) => {
        console.log(event); // Outputs {showContentSideBar: true} or {showContentSideBar: false}
        // write showContentSideBar to a public var and use it for ngIf on sideBar component
      });
  }
```

app.component template

```
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <div class="main">
      <header></header>
      <div class="content><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <content-sidebar *ngIf="showContentSideBar"></content-sidebar>
```

That way you can simply ngIf the `content-sidebar` in your app (root) component using the information that you get in the `subscribe`. Only one root component/template will be needed for that approach.

Sadly the code to read the data from the route looks a bit bloated, but as far as I know there is no better solution for that. See also on Github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9662

Todd Motto´s solution: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Comment: Hi, @spierala! Thanks for the answer! The content-sidebar is unique for each page hence it should be declared inside router-outlet.

Comment: I think then it is more a question of the CSS.
If you place the content-sidebar inside the router-outlet then app-component will still hold sidebar, header, footer. And the router outlet will hold the content with content-sidebar.

The CSS for that structure could look like this: https://codepen.io/spierala/pen/wvBWaWV
(I also used bootstrap flex classes, but the main magic is position absolute on the content-sidebar). Also `content-container` is not allowed to have positioning itself.

Comment: I added a more appropriate answer - I hope :)